# How to prove that limit is equal to zero

Tags: integration, limits, distribution-theory

How to prove that:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(-\log(-x) \phi(x)|_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} -\log(x) \phi(x)|_{\epsilon}^{+\infty})$$
where
$\phi(x) $  is any test function

is equal to $0$.

It seems pretty obvious, but I need formal proof. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is a test function, it has compact support and the limit becomes
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \log \epsilon (\phi(\epsilon) - \phi(-\epsilon) ) \right) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( (\epsilon \log \epsilon) { (\phi(\epsilon) - \phi(-\epsilon) ) \over \epsilon} \right)$.

Since $\phi$ is smooth, it is differentiable at $0$ hence ${ (\phi(\epsilon) - \phi(-\epsilon) ) \over \epsilon}$ is bounded for small $\epsilon$, and since
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} ( \epsilon \log \epsilon) = 0$, we have the desired result.

Comment: how do we know that $\log(\infty)\phi(\infty)$ is equal to zero? $\infty \cdot 0$ is not defined

Comment: I am presuming that you are evaluating some integral with limits at $\pm \infty$. In that case since $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x$ sufficiently large, the limits can be replaced by a finite number.